# No custom Error in code snippet?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was running the snippet mentioned in the **[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37916691/2065039)**.. Due to post it just went on showing the actual server `error` instead of custom `error`. Basically we always been taught to display users with `custom error` instead of actual server error page IMHO. `jsFiddle` has handled this in fact. Should this be treated as actual behavior or is this something Community has to take care? Below is the screenshot for the reference.

[image: Server Error Image]

Comment: Do you know why a custom error page is typically suggested? It is due to the default error pages showing stack traces when there is an exception. Since there is no exception here, I don't see the point.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan IMHO every error must be a sort of custom errors to the user and it is not a good practice to show these type of errors in any application.

Comment: Yep, that's your opinion. My opinion differs :). BTW, the community can take care of it; edit the answer to update the code to add `preventDefault`, or change it to not be a snippet.

Comment: Yep, not an issue.. I respect your opinion too.. Am doing that with the said answer..